# how to move duplicate rows into columns so that each row is unique

Tags: sql

I work with patient data.  When joining the table to show which clician saw the patient i get multiple rows if the patient saw more than one clinician.  I have used a row number function to try and highlight the second clinician.  However, i need each row to represent one patient and additional columns to show the names of the clinicians if there is more than one.

i have the following data output from my query

```
patient Clinician seen  Clinician number  
1       joe                  1  
2       dan                  1  
2       peter                2  
3       sandra               1  
4       andrea               1  
4       steve                2  
5       helen                1
```

I need the output to be:

```
patient Clinician seen 1    person seen 2  
1   joe                     NULL  
2   dan                     peter  
3   sandra                  NULL  
4   andrea                  steve  
5   helen                   NULL
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT

patient,  
Clinician_seen,  
,ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER(PARTITION BY patient ORDER BY Clinician_seen asc )

FROM
patients  
clinicians on patients.patietn_id = clinicians.patietn_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT patient,
       MAX(case when cnum = 1 then Clinician_seen end) as Clinician1,
       MAX(case when cnum = 2 then Clinician_seen end) as Clinician2
FROM (SELECT p.patient, c.Clinician_seen,  
             ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY p.patient ORDER BY c.Clinician_seen asc ) as cnum
      FROM patients p JOIN
           clinicians c
           on p.patient_id = c.patient_id 
     ) t
GROUP BY patient;
```